# Initialize a hashmap in a more compact way without external libraries

Tags: java

Is there a way to make this code more compact? With less lines without using libraries?
I am using Java 7

```
public enum CustomType {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C,
}

private static final Map<Integer, CustomType> typeMappings = new HashMap<>();

static {
    typeMappings.put(513, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    typeMappings.put(520, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    typeMappings.put(528, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    typeMappings.put(530, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    typeMappings.put(532, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    typeMappings.put(501, CustomType.TYPE_B);
    typeMappings.put(519, CustomType.TYPE_B);
    typeMappings.put(529, CustomType.TYPE_B);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have full control over both the mapping, and the enum classes, then the more traditional way to solve this problem is to embed the mapping in to the enums.

```
public enum CustomType {
    TYPE_A(513, 520, 528, 530, 532),
    TYPE_B(501, 519, 529),
    TYPE_C();

    private static final Map<Integer, CustomType> typeMappings = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (CustomType ct : values()) {
            for (int v : ct.mapto) {
                typeMappings.put(v, ct);
            }
        }
    }

    private final int mapto[];
    CustomType(int ... mapto) {
        this.mapto = mapto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! So the best coding style for this is to put the initialization inside the enum? What is the use of  `mapto[]`? I am confused on this

Comment: The order of the initialization process of an enum is complicated. Would be happy to talk more about it in the [2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: Hmm... this is interesting... is the enum values and the enum constructor called *before* the static block for enums? Got a JLS reference for this?

Comment: @SimonForsberg: From [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3): *"These fields are implicitly declared in the same order as the corresponding enum constants, before any static fields explicitly declared in the body of the declaration of E."* In this case, the enum constants are declared before the static initializer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make it more compact:

```
Map<Integer, CustomType> typeMappings2 = new HashMap<Integer, CustomType>() {{
    put(513, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    put(520, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    put(528, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    put(530, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    put(532, CustomType.TYPE_A);
    put(501, CustomType.TYPE_B);
    put(519, CustomType.TYPE_B);
    put(529, CustomType.TYPE_B);
}};
```

... but aesthetically it is not very beautiful either.

Comment: Antot - the initializer block that you have is a very esoteric, and seldom used way to do this. It's also creating a new anonymous class.... While I agree it makes the code shorter, the way it works is obtuse, and so on.

Comment: @Rolfl: You are right. That was the reason why I said that this solution was not very nice. I'd not apply it to a serious piece of code. It is just an example of how the original code may be shortened, in reply to the question.

Comment: @rolfl: I've used this method for initializing ArrayLists before.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 That doesn't necessarily make it a recommended way. While it might have worked for you then, I still wouldn't recommend to do it that way. I'd rather do `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(A, B, C...))`